# How to add a jar to the classpath in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

The program runs as it should in eclipse, however when I try running it as a Jar it throws a noClassDefFoundError.
I assume this is due to an imported jar (commons-io-2.4.jar) that does not get added to the classpath. Apparently I only need to add this jar to the lib folder. Problem is, I can't find this folder (in the workspace there are only .setting, bin and src, as well as a .classpath and a .project file) and I haven't found any options in the Projects properties that would solve this problem.
 
How do I do this in eclipse?

Comment: Are you facing this issue when exporting your application as runnable jar? which version of eclipse are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by imported if not it being in the workspace?

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar in source dir or project folder then select in eclipse, right-click will give you to add the jar in classpath

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work